# assigning associative array in smarty

Tags: arrays, smarty, associative-array

So what I'm trying to achieve is assign multiple values in to a smarty array on the indexes that I want. It's hard to describe it, so I'll just show it:

```
{assign var='paymentTypes' 
value=','|explode:"$paymentMethods[50],$paymentMethods[51],
$paymentMethods[11],$paymentMethods[10],$paymentMethods[12],
$paymentMethods[99],$paymentMethods[100]"}
```

(Formatted for readability)

So now I have a paymentTypes array with the values placed on the keys starting from 0. What I want is to keep the keys that were in paymentMethods array - 50, 51, 11.. etc.

And it has to be done totally in Smarty template file. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. The needed associative array was for a HTML Select tag. So I just used {html_options} with value and output attributes instead of options. I assigned one array just for values and another just for output.

I had this:

```
{html_options options=$paymentTypes}
```

But I didn't want to show all of the values from paymentTypes array, but I had to have them in the array. So what I did was this:

```
{assign var='paymentTypesOutput' value=','|explode:"$paymentTypes[50],
$paymentTypes[51],$paymentTypes[11],$paymentTypes[10],$paymentTypes[12],
$paymentTypes[99],$paymentTypes[100]"}

{assign var='paymentTypesValues' value=','|explode:"50,51,11,10,12,99,100"}

{html_options values=$paymentTypesValues output=$paymentTypesOutput}
```

It's not the most elegant solution - but it works.